# Excel Chart - Line Per Week, value by Day

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office-for-mac

I have a table with 3 columns: Week of year (number), Day of week (number: 1 for sunday, 2 for mondai, etc...) and earnings (number also).

I would like to have a chart where the X axis are the days (from 1 to 7) and a line for every week, being the Y value, the earning for that week on that particular day

How can i do that?

Comment: Try pivot chart,  it should solve your issue,  it's quite intuitive to set it up.

Comment: @MátéJuhász awesome! that did it! post as answer tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical task for a [pivot chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-PivotTable-and-PivotChart-reports-527c8fa3-02c0-445a-a2db-7794676bce96?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

You can insert it in insert / pivot chart, then customize as you need.